# User Not Found While Changing Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is wrong with the following code that is causing it produce a "User Not Found" Error. The purpose of the code is to allow logged in users to change their passwords.

```
[Authorize]
public partial class TestController : Controller
{
    UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager =
new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>());

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult ChangePass(ChangePassTestVM model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                 var id = Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();
                 var result = MembershipUser. userManager.ChangePassword(id, model.OldPassword, model.NewPassword);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return View(model);
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.ToString();`after putting a breakpoint at that line?

Comment: @CodeNotFound In the following format as expected 0bff27e9-cdc1-4784-g352-8fa8fa143d61

Comment: It's weird. So make sure that this Id exists in the databse and so you're using the correct database too.

Comment: @CodeNotFound very strange if I could login with that user why there would be any possibility that the id does not exist.

Comment: Another way is that maybe the given Id are NOT the id used by the Membership as a key too :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using - Microsoft.Aspnet.Identity version 2 then there are some better way to reset the password

```
string resetToken = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(model.Id);

IdentityResult passwordChangeResult = await UserManager.ResetPasswordAsync(model.Id, resetToken, model.NewPassword);
```

If you are having version-1 then you can try using "RemovePassword", and "AddPassword" methods of "userManager" instance.

Comment: This is a Simple Membership